# android : Get data Using volley (key : header)

Tags: android, get, android-volley

sorry for my beginner question, i being learning about `volley` . ok just to the point

i want to get data using `volley` but in this case not using `url` but using `key` and `header`

example :
in `retrofit` when i try to get all `json`'s data i do this (the part of code):

```
  //Add Interceptor
                    RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                            request.addHeader("theApiKey", "23xsd94832ccsdf4jzcxz");
                        }
                    };
```

but how when i using `volley`?

when it just using `url`, i do this (the part of code) :

```
 protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mQueue = CustomVolleyRequestQueue.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                .getRequestQueue();
        String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk";
        final CustomJSONObjectRequest jsonRequest = new CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method
                .GET, url,
                new JSONObject(), this, this);
        jsonRequest.setTag(REQUEST_TAG);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mQueue.add(jsonRequest);
            }
        });
    }
```

**my question, how if there is no `url` but `key` and `xxxssddcdsvsdfd` ?**
thanks.

Comment: From the OpenWeatherMap site, do you mean that `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/city?id=524901&APPID={APIKEY} `?

Comment: no. it just some examples of tutorial using direct `url`, how if just use `apiKey` and `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` . i mean `xxxxxxx` is the ID key

Comment: How can client get data from server without knowing server'url?